# How to run loader icon on deleted row rendered from a list in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hi i am rendering a list of photos from api response. When i delete on one of them, only that row should show the loader. But as of now i see the loader icon on all rows

```
let boilerImages;
    if( listOfPhotos.data!== undefined && listOfPhotos.data.task && listOfPhotos.data.task.metadata !==''){
    boilerImages =   
      listOfPhotos.data &&
      JSON.parse(listOfPhotos.data.task.metadata).files.map((token, index) => {
        console.log('key', index)
        const fileUrl = `url/${token}?subscription-key="something"`
        return (
        <div className="list-wrapper" key={token+index}>
          <div className="img-block">
            <img className="img-block-bucket" src={fileUrl}/>


            /* This is the part of loader - start */                
              {
                this.props.isDeleting ? 
                <SvgIcon
                  svg={"icons/loading-spinner.svg"}
                  key={index}
                 fromUrl={true}
                 className={"deleting-svg"}
                />: 
               <label className="img-block-file-name"> 
                 {this.getFileName(fileUrl)}
               </label>
             }
           /* This is the part of loader - end */ 

          </div>
          <button disabled={this.props.isDeleting} className="del-block" onClick={() => removePhoto(token)}>
            <SvgIcon
              svg={"icons/ic_trash_bin_48_black.svg"}
              key={index}
              fromUrl={true}
              className={!this.props.isDeleting ? "del-block-svg" : "del-block--disabled"}
            />
          </button>
        </div>
      )});
  }
```

this.props.isDeleting is set to true in redux state, when i call removePhoto action and this.props.isDeleting is set to false in redux state, when i call renderPhoto action on update

Comment: is this a typo or actual bug that you are looking for `&& ) &&`

Comment: yes. sorry. will remove that

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `isDeleting` being a boolean, it will need to be an array of booleans where each entry is the loading state of the list item, then you just need to do something like

```
 {(this.props.isDeleting[index] && ) && (
  <SvgIcon
    svg={"icons/loading-spinner.svg"}
    key={index}
    fromUrl={true}
    className={"deleting-svg"}
  />)}
```

Comment: Can you please relate to the scenario which i have

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bill. So instead of setting true or false at redux store. I tried having an object. So i used the *token* passed in my action - removePhoto

**When i called removePhoto action**

```
   this.props.isDeleting: {
      ...state.data,
      key: action.payload, //key: token
      status: true
   }
```

**When i called renderPhoto action**

```
   this.props.isDeleting: {
      ...state.data,
      key: null,
      status: false
   }
```

so the component has code something like this:

```
let boilerImages;
    if( listOfPhotos.data!== undefined && listOfPhotos.data.task && listOfPhotos.data.task.metadata !==''){
    boilerImages =   
      listOfPhotos.data &&
      JSON.parse(listOfPhotos.data.task.metadata).files.map((token, index) => {
        const fileUrl = `url/${token}?subscription-key="something"`
        return (
        <div className="list-wrapper" key={index}>
          <div className="img-block">
            <img className="img-block-bucket" src={fileUrl} onError={() => this.updateCRM(token)}/>

            /* This is the part of loader - start */ 
            {
              this.props.isDeleting.key === token ? 
                <SvgIcon
                  svg={"icons/loading-spinner.svg"}
                  key={index}
                  fromUrl={true}
                  className={"delete-loader"}
                /> : 
                <label className="img-block-file-name">
                  {this.getFileName(fileUrl)}
                </label>
            }
            /* This is the part of loader - end */ 

          </div>
          <button disabled={this.props.isDeleting.status} className="del-block" onClick={() => removePhoto(token)}>
            <SvgIcon
              svg={"icons/ic_trash_bin_48_black.svg"}
              key={index}
              fromUrl={true}
              className={!this.props.isDeleting.status ? "del-block--enabled" : "del-block--disabled"}
            />
          </button>
        </div>
      )});
  }
```